# AnimatedExpandableListView items not selectable

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have an AnimatedExpandableListView whose items expand and collapse when clicked by the user. **I want the selected item to highlight when it's expanded and go back to its original state (non-highlighted) when collapsed.**

AnimatedExpandableListView's xml:

```
<com.packagename.library.AnimatedExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

LinearLayout of AnimatedExpandableListView item whose background I want to change when selected:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"/>
```

And the background drawable for the selected state listener:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_linear_layout" android:color="@color/white" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_linear_layout" android:color="@color/white" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_linear_layout" />
</selector>
```

**Setting `choiceMode=singleChoice` and adding the `list_selector` drawable to the background of items of a regular ListView works fine, but it doesn't seem to work on an AnimatedExpandableListView.**

[Here](https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView) is the github for the AnimatedExpandableListView class I'm using for my project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code- in your Adapters getGroupView method

```
  if (isExpanded){
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }else {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(0);
            }
```